# cannot find symbol class NotificationManagerCompat

Tags: android, push-notification, ibeacon-android

I am trying to build a notification method that would result in a notification appearing on the locked screen when a particular beacon is detected.  My understanding is that I need to include .setVisibility(0) in the following code:

```
public void showNotification(Beacon beacon) {

    Resources r = getResources();
    int random = (int)System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder)
            .setContentTitle("Beacons Found")
            .setContentText(beacon.getID().toString())
            .setVisibility(0)  // allow notification to appear on locked screen
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(random, notification);

}
```

I have the above code, but when I run it it says "cannot find symbol variable SetVisibility".  I have done some research online and it seems I need to import this:

```
 import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
```

But if I include this import statement, it would say "cannot find symbol class NotificationManagerCompat"

What should I do?  I have already installed Android Support Repository SDK and have the "android-support-v4.jar in the libs folder of the project

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have this error come up, because you added a new module to your project.

To fix it, change `minSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, and `compileSdkVersion` to match the `build.gradle` in your original module.

After that set `minifyEnabled` to `false`.

What it actually fixed it for me (while using Android Studio 3.0.1) was setting facebook to

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
```

Also check your other libs and dependencies and your build file.

My current build file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven  {
            url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
        }
        // maven  {
        //    url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
        // since Android Studio 3.0.0
        // or google()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```