# NotificationCompat Builder and Android O

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

It's probably a silly question, but I cant figure out what's wrong.

I'm facing a problem with the update to Android 26 and NotificationCompat.
I'm trying to use the new Builder:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context, String channelId)
```

but when I build it states that I'm giving to many arguments and it's only expecting to have Context context.

SDK and SDK tools are updated to version 26 and I tried adding some dependencies in gradle.build, with no luck:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

in the java file I'm importing v4.app.NotificationCompat:

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

It still give the same error, like NotificationCompat is not updated.

Can you help me? :D

Comment: Have you tried the basic things like build, re-build, invalidate caches and restart? Because everything seems correct.

Comment: Several times .-.

Comment: You're using different versions of the support library, for the best compatibility they should all be the same. You've got three different versions.

Comment: Same...
(I have also updated my post)

Comment: Maybe this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259902/cannot-find-symbol-class-notificationmanagercompat/47674791#47674791) will help you.